# VLC as standard for AVI files

Tags: vlc

How can I make VLC Player the default player for AVI files. So if I double click on an AVI file, it will open with VLC instead of the Movie Player.

I've tried by going to:

System Settings - Details - Default Applications and select VLC Player instead of Movie Player, for video.

Is there and other way of accomplishing this?

UBUNTU 12:04 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right clicking the avi file, then Properties, and then Open With. This allows you to change the default program per file type